# How to get MD5 Code from SourceForge

Tags: c#, md5, sourceforge, md5-file

I'm coding a application, but I have a problem in Autoupdate function. The Autoupdate function can be described:
 - First, I upload my program to SourceForge
 - When user chose Update, the program will check MD5 code all file, and compare it to the same on SourceForge.
But I don't know how to get MD5 code of a file on SourceForge, (C# Code)
Someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: http://checksumtool.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can run regex over the output of a project feed.
i.e. if you know the specific file you're going to download you can find the `media:content` line in

```
http://sourceforge.net/api/file/index/project-id/<PROJECTID>/mtime/desc/limit/50/rss
```

Then you can use some regex to get the hash for that file;

```
(?!<media:hash algo=\"md5\">)([a-fA-F\d]{32})(?=</media:hash>)
```